# Looking to split column based on other column criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for help to split a column based on criteria in other column and date range = 2022.01.12

This is `my_table` example :

| date | area | move | qty | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.12 7:00 | L1a | in | 1 | item1 |
| 01.12 7:00 | L2 | out | 2 | item1 |
| 01.12 7:01 | L1b | in | 1 | item2 |
| 01.12 7:01 | L02 | out | 2 | item2 |
| 01.12 7:02 | L1a | in | 5 | item1 |
| 01.12 7:02 | L02 | out | 7 | item1 |
| 01.12 7:03 | L1 | in | 1 | item3 |
| 01.12 7:03 | L2 | out | 1 | item3 |

Expected result :

| date | area_in | move_in | qty | area_out | move_out | qty | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.12 | L1a | in | 1 | L2 | out | 2 | item1 |
| 01.12 | L1b | in | 1 | L02 | out | 2 | item2 |
| 01.12 | L1a | in | 5 | L02 | out | 7 | item1 |
| 01.12 | L1 | in | 1 | L2 | out | 1 | item3 |

Looking forwards for your kind help.

Comment: This looks like a pivot but by what logic are the *out* rows paired with the *in* rows?

Comment: how can an alghorithm determine, which rows belong together, the table needs acolumn which tells the query that

Comment: @nbk : always the out below the in they all come as pair, that's the only logic available; i don't know how to create a sequence column for each pair

Comment: tables are by nature unsorted, so what you defined as pair isn't one for sql, they are not a pair with out another column

Comment: @David you are missing a cruicial piece of information, there must be a column that defines the order of the rows or a key that relates your rows. A table is an unordered set of rows unless you define the order.

Comment: @Stu, that's what am looking for define the order which originally not available (2:out -1:in  ,4:out-3:in,6:out-5:in,.....etc)

Comment: @nbk are you referring to ROWID?

Comment: a auto increment would do it. but you would need an algorithm why not add a row with the same number for in and out that belong together, that would make the query simple

Comment: @nbk, cause originally not available

Comment: maybe you have a timestamp that would give the hole table an order

Comment: @nbk i did added item1,2,3...etc to identify the difference,kindlly advice if that helpful; thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I is a quite simple pivot for that data

But if the time don't fit together, you still would need a better group value

```
SELECT
  [date], 
  MAX(CASE WHEN [move] = 'in' THen [area] ELSe NULL END) area_in,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [move] = 'in' THen [move] ELSe NULL END) move_in,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [move] = 'in' THen [qty] ELSe NULL END) qty_in,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [move] = 'out' THen [area] ELSe NULL END) area_out,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [move] = 'out' THen [move] ELSe NULL END) move_out,
  MAX(CASE WHEN [move] = 'out' THen [qty] ELSe NULL END) qty_out
  , [item]
FROM tab1
GROUP BY [date],  [item]
ORDER By [date]
```

| date | area_in | move_in | qty_in | area_out | move_out | qty_out | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.12 7:00 | L1a | in | 1 | L2 | out | 2 | item1 |
| 01.12 7:01 | L1b | in | 1 | L02 | out | 2 | item2 |
| 01.12 7:02 | L1a | in | 5 | L02 | out | 7 | item1 |
| 01.12 7:03 | L1 | in | 1 | L2 | out | 1 | item3 |

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hXxJ8aVO)

Comment: appreciated your kind patience and support, if i have 500 move in & out i will need to repeat all the MAX CASE line as represented above ?

Comment: run the query on your system, you said ther are only pairs, so you need 3 column for in and 3 for out, and you can display millions or billions of moves, in short rum the query it is so how you need it

Comment: i did use your shared fiddle and it really work; thx again for your help

Comment: just a curious question, if i want to add a condition WHERE for example : where area_in = 'L1a' is possible ? i know this was not part of the question

Comment: SQL Server is very picky in some regards, you would do it so https://dbfiddle.uk/mb2G6ZvC  but next time ask  a new question

Comment: you are amaaaazing; thx alot